# check status of ZFS pool on Linux host with Icinga monitoring system

Tags: linux, zfs

I have a server which is used for backup storage. It's running ZFS on Linux, configured with a RAID z2 data pool and shared via Samba.
I need to monitor the ZFS filesystem to at least be able to see how much space is available.

I thought a simple check_disk plugin will do this job.

I'm able to execute the command from the icinga server cli:

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H <hostname> -c check_disk -a 10% 20% /data/backups
DISK OK - free space: /data/backups 4596722 MB (30% inode=99%);| /data/backups=10355313MB;13456832;11961628;0;14952036
```

But the GUI shows the following error:

```
DISK CRITICAL - /data/backups is not accessible: No such file or directory
```

It works under the check_mk monitoring system, but we are migrating from check_mk right now.
I don't have any problems with checking other filesystems (root, boot) in Icinga on this machine.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Line is in /etc/icinga/objects/linux.cfg on the server:

```
check_command               check_nrpe_1arg!check_backup
```

Line is in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg on the client

```
command[check_backup]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p  $ARG3$
```